# Does Android support Teredo?

Tags: android, networking, ssh, ipv6

I need to access *SSH* server on **IPv6** address from my Android phone but can't, since I am on **IPv4** network. On **IPv6** network it works. Does Android somehow support *Teredo*/*miredo* so I can access **IPv6** addresses on **IPv4** networks?

**Edit:** After downvotes I decided to illustrate the problem graphically.

### The problem

[image: Teredo problem explanation]
As you can see, it's not possible to connect to **IPv6** address from **IPv4** network. *Teredo* would be completely sufficient, but isn't apparently available on Android. I'm looking for similar solution as *Teredo*, that's the purpose of this question.

My ISP is **ignoring** my requests at this moment and I **do not** have access to the router.

### Current workaround

[image: Teredo problem temporary solution]

I am using my previous university server which runs dualstack **IPv4** and **IPv6**. I was able to *SSH* from Android to this server and from there to my home server. I was able to make *SSH* tunnel for *VNC* or *HTTPS*.

This solution was sufficient for basic needs, however I am sure there is a better way.

Comment: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/32393

Answer (score 2):

Teredo is not widely used. It is not usually recommended.

Your local (wifi) network: If you have control of your network, DNS64+NAT64 would work for you, as a very common approach out there in the wild.

Your cell network: Android has hooks to enable 464xlat, *if* your provider offers v6 with DNS64+NAT64. If not, this obviously won't work for you.

Failing those, consider futzing with a dual-stacked host and ssh ProxyCommand. Or add a v4 addr to the target host, and put an A-record in DNS with different subdomain (ipv4.foo.bar).

Consider also (politely!) grouching at your provider(s), or looking at alternatives.